# How to load this dynamic website with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium4, selenium-webdriver-python

Trying to load this dynamic website but failed. Anyone can help?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://apply.95559.com.cn/personbank/portals/ptQuotaQryCoins.do')
```

Comment: What do you mean it "failed"?  Do you get some sort of error?

Answer (score 0):

Not that super clear about the issue you are facing while loading the [dynamic website](https://apply.95559.com.cn/personbank/portals/ptQuotaQryCoins.do). However I was able to load the website using the following code block:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
  s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  driver.get('https://apply.95559.com.cn/personbank/portals/ptQuotaQryCoins.do')
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: apply_95559_com]